Color in mesh darker than the actual texture, even with the shader nodes that I set up
I have come across a problem where the texture on the mesh in the viewport is darker than the actual texture in the texture painter. I understand that the texture on meshes will be effected by the lighting, and the other factors that I am too lazy to list. But I have made it so that the texture has a emission property with a shade feature, anime style, but it seems that the texture is still darker than the actual mesh. Is there anything that I can do, or is this something that I have to deal with?
Link to the actual file below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VyVCLolEFQbZ2nghkv7QNiNP8Ok4AsgV/view?usp=sharing


Don't do whatever this is supposed to be in the shader:

Instead connect the texture directly to material output and set color management to "Standard" without any look:

If you use any shaders and lighting, it affects the colors of your textures, because shading is supposed to do that - shade. Color management also affects colors as AgX transform remaps the linear lighting information in the scene to form an image in certain more limited color space. If you need to render something with shading and still match the colors as much as possible, you could try using Khronos PBR Neutral color transform that is supposed to help with that. It will still not give you identical colors because they are supposed to be affected by shaders and lighting.
You can still use NPR shaders with standard color transform and choose the exact colors to remain under certain conditions:

Here I am using the pure color from the texture and mixing it with it's version modified with Hue/Saturation/Value node for shadows. The mask is made out of Diffuse BSDF converted to RGB and remapped to black and white. Where the mask is completely black, the second output will be fully visible and since it's the unmodified texture, the colors will match. This way the shader still affects the colors but in a very specific way you choose.
